# Is there a way to add a table to an SQL CE database file using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

**PLEASE READ THE CONTENT OF THIS QUESTION BEFORE YOU CLOSE IT!**

I am NOT using Code First. I'm updating an SQL Compact Edition database file. Is there a way I can add a table using to this an SQL command? Is there a way to get an OLEDB connection to the database? The EF connection string does not work in OLEDB.

Comment: You can get the sqlceconnection object from the DbContext.Database property, and then run a create table statement using that connection object.

Comment: `DbContext.Database.Connection` is not an `OleDbConnecion`. What type of command should I create in order to use it?

Comment: Never mind. `SqlCeCommand`. Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a SqlCeConnnection object from the DbContext.Database.Connection property, and then run a create table statement using that connection object, ie SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()